# Enviar mensagem do botão

Tags: java, android

Queria perguntar como posso enviar mensagem de um botão ou a mensagem esta escrita nesse botão

Comment: Pelo que parece você está querendo aprender como programar para Android em uma pergunta, isso não dá cara, recomendo que estude Java, caso ainda não saiba, e depois entre em Android com alguns vídeos ou artigos

Answer (score 1):

Exemplo:

```
Button botao = (Button) findViewById(R.id.meuBotao);

String mensagemEscritaNoBotao = botao.getText();

botao.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
     public void onClick(View v) {
           // Ação para ser executada quando o botão é clicado
     }
});
```

Comment: Obrigado pela dica. Poderia me dizer como fica a parte de XML por favor

Comment: o R.id.meuBotao é o id que você encontra no XML

Comment: Com esse código que voçe me enviou posso criar uma acção para gravar no Firebade ou seja como posso fazer isso